# Left alt and right alt produce different results

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, autohotkey, alt-key

My script:

```
#MenuMaskKey vkFF
#SingleInstance Force

SendMode Input
SetTitleMatchMode Regex

#IfWinActive ahk_exe (chrome|msedge).exe
  !l::Send ^{Tab}
#IfWinActive
```

In Chrome, when using `!l` with the left <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is sent without side effects, however, if using `!l` with the right <kbd>alt</kbd> instead, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is sent and the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key *is never released*, if I press <kbd>j</kbd> after that, the download page will be opened.

Does anyone know the root cause of this behavior and how to fix this?

AHK version: 1.1.33.10

Comment: Have you tried it as a stand-alone script? Use only this code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere.

Comment: @user3419297 Thanks for the reminder! I figured that `#MenuMaskKey vkFF` combined with `SendMode Input` is causing the issue, removing either one will solve it, why is this?